# Is [Weak self] always needed when dealing with URLSession?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, nsurlsession, retain-cycle

I can't figure out if I need to use `[weak self]` in this situation or not ?

HTTPClient.swift:

```
struct HTTPClient {
    let session = URLSession.shared

    func get(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {
        session.dataTask(with: url) { data, urlResponse, error in
        completion(data) // assume everything will go well
      }.resume()
    }
}
```

Service.swift

```
struct Service {
    let httpClient: HTTPClient

    init(httpClient: HTTPClient = HTTPClient()) {
        self.httpClient = httpClient
    }

    func fetchUser(completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
        httpClient.get("urlToGetUser") { data in
          // transform data to User 
          completion(user)
        } 
    }
}
```

ViewModel.swift

```
class ViewModel {
   let service: Service
   let user: User?
   var didLoadData: ((User) -> Void)?

    init(service: Service) {
        self.service = service
        loadUser()
    }

   func loadUser() {
     service.fetchUser { [weak self] user in // is  [weak self] really needed ?
            self?.user = user
            self?.didLoadData?(user)
        }
   }
}
```

is it really needed here to user `[weak self]` ? and is there a rule on how to check if it's needed in general when we deal with an API that we don't know what's happening to the closure ? or that does not matter (it's up to us to decide) ?

Comment: "is there a rule on how to check if it's needed in general when we deal with an API that we don't know what's happening to the closure?" Yes. Try it without and see if a leak is caused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the example you've given, `[weak self]` is potentially unnecessary. It depends on what you want to happen if `ViewModel` is released before the request completes.

As noted in the `URLSessionDataTask` docs (emphasis mine):

> After you create a task, you start it by calling its resume() method. The session then maintains a strong reference to the task **until the request finishes or fails**; you don’t need to maintain a reference to the task unless it’s useful for your app’s internal bookkeeping.

The session has a strong reference to the task. The task has a strong reference to the closure. The closure has a strong reference to the `ViewModel`. As long as the `ViewModel` doesn't have a strong reference to the task (which it doesn't in the code you provided), then there's no cycle.

The question is whether you want to ensure that the `ViewModel` continues to exist long enough for the closure to execute. If you do (or don't care), then you can use a simple strong reference. If you want to prevent the task from keeping the `ViewModel` alive, then you should use a weak reference.

This is how you need to think about reference cycles. There is no general rule "use `weak` here." You use `weak` when that's what you mean; when you don't want this closure to keep `self` around until it is released. That particularly is true if it creates a cycle. But there's no general answer for "does this create a cycle." It depends on what pieces hold references.

This also points to where your current API design is not as good as it could be. You're passing `didLoadData` in `init`. That very likely is going to create reference cycles and force your caller to use `weak`. If instead you made `didLoadDdata` a completion handler on `loadUser()`, then you could avoid that problem and make life easier on the caller.

```
func loadUser(completion: @escaping ((User?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    service.fetchUser {
        self?.user = user
        didLoadData?(user)
    }
}
```

(Your current API has a race condition in any case. You're starting `loadUser()` before `didLoadData` can be set. You may be assuming that the completion handler won't complete before you've set `dataDidLoad`, but there's no real promise of that. It's probably true, but it's fragile at best.)

Comment: How did you identify that the `URLSessionDataTask` keeps a reference of the closure? As an apple API we can't see its internals and the documentation doesn't appear to mention this.

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna The signature tells us this, because the closure is marked `@escaping` in Swift. Completion handlers are always retained by the thing they're passed to, or they can't be completion handlers, so in ObjC we know it by convention, but in Swift the signature additionally tells us when closures escape.

Comment: Would this not mean we'd have retain cycles any time an `@escaping` closure 1. references `self` 2. Is passed in to a function belonging to an object that is a property of `self`. When I run a scenario like this in playgrounds this doesn't appear to be the case at least where URLSession is concerned: https://gist.github.com/Deco354/716cd67ae0f733b5cff0b330e9ab8f18

Comment: You do have a retain cycle until the completion handler is released. That's explained by "The session then maintains a strong reference to the task until the request finishes or fails." Once the task completes, it is released by the session. That destroys the task and the closure that it's holding, which releases the reference back to self, breaking the retain cycle. It is also very common and good practice for objects to release their completion blocks once they fire, but that isn't explicitly documented here, just that the task will be released.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading, since you don't have proof, that task has strong ref to a completion closure, if it is not - it is not a "retain cycle"

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is not with the use of URLSession but with the fact that you are retaining a function in your view controller:

```
class ViewModel {
    var didLoadData: ((User) -> Void)?
}
```

If the `didLoadData` function mentions `self` (i.e. the ViewModel instance) implicitly or explicitly, you have a retain cycle and a memory leak unless you say `weak self` or `unowned self`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the `[weak self]` is needed in my ViewController when referring to `self` (ViewController). But does that affect the need of `[weak self]` in the viewModel in `loadUser` function, that is my concern